# NonSerialized on property

Tags: c#, .net, serialization, properties

When I write code like this

```
[XmlIgnore]
[NonSerialized]
public List<string> paramFiles { get; set; }
```

I get the following error:

```
Attribute 'NonSerialized' is not valid on this declaration type.
It is only valid on 'field' declarations.
```

If I write

```
[field: NonSerialized]
```

I get the following warning

```
'field' is not a valid attribute location for this declaration.
Valid attribute locations for this declaration are 'property'.
All attributes in this block will be ignored.
```

If I write

```
[property: NonSerialized]
```

I get the following error (again):

```
Attribute 'NonSerialized' is not valid on this declaration type.
It is only valid on 'field' declarations.
```

How can I use `[NonSerialized]` on a property?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Well... the first error says that you can't do that...
from http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.nonserializedattribute.aspx

```
 [AttributeUsageAttribute(AttributeTargets.Field, Inherited = false)]
 [ComVisibleAttribute(true)]
 public sealed class NonSerializedAttribute : Attribute
```

I suggest using backing field

```
 public List<string> paramFiles { get { return list;}  set { list = value; } }
 [NonSerialized]
 private List<string> list;
```

Comment: Using the suggested backing field does not seem to work. The property is still being serialized.

Comment: Yes it works, but not in every class named AaaSerializer. Which serializer are you using?

Comment: The correct attribute is [NonSerialized], not [NonSerializable]

Comment: oy...what if your "backing field" is a method?

Comment: Which serializer do you use?

Comment: NonSerialized will work for BinaryFormatter (at least) which serializes fields, and probably won't work for Json or XML serializers which serialize properties.

Answer (score 80):

Simple use:

```
[XmlIgnore]
[ScriptIgnore]
public List<string> paramFiles { get; set; }
```

Hopefully, it helps.

Comment: Indeed this even works in classic ASP.NET Web Service scenario by completely hiding the property name from the consumer (a great trick for those stuck in pre-WCF project)

Comment: I did not need to use [ScriptIgnore] to make this work

Comment: @AntonioNicolaasTeyken It depends on what you're using to serialize the data. In my case, [ScriptIgnore] prevented Json serialization.

Comment: One more note: `ScriptIgnoreAttribute` is available in the `System.Web.Script.Serialization` namespace ([MSDN](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.web.script.serialization.scriptignoreattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8)).

Comment: Just to be clear, this works for binary serializer?  Because the question already has XmlIgnore in the example so not sure how this can help.

Answer (score 51):

From C# 7.3 you may attach attributes to the backing field of auto-implemented properties.

Hence the following should work if you update your project's language to C# 7.3:

```cs
[field: NonSerialized]
public List<string> paramFiles { get; set; }
```

Comment: This should be re-marked as the best answer, because it's pretty awesome.

Comment: When I use this the property is still serialized with XmlSerializer

Answer (score 14):

For those using JSON instead of XML you can use the `[JsonIgnore]` attribute on properties:

```
[JsonIgnore]
public List<string> paramFiles { get; set; }
```

Available in both [Newtonsoft.Json](https://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PropertyJsonIgnore.htm) and [System.Text.Json (.NET Core 3.0)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.serialization.jsonignoreattribute?view=netcore-3.0).

Comment: Please note, which package that is doing serialisation matters!
If you're doing serialisation with Newtonsoft, don't use the `JsonIgnore` from System.Text.Json (or vice versa).

Answer (score 6):

As of .NET 3.0, you can use [DataContract](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datacontractattribute?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-3.0) instead of Serializable. With the DataContract though, you will need to either "opt-in" by marking the serializable fields with the [DataMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.datamemberattribute?view=netframework-3.0) attribute; or "opt-out" using the [IgnoreDataMember](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.runtime.serialization.ignoredatamemberattribute?view=netframework-3.0).

The main difference between opt-in vs opt-out is that opt-out by default will only serialize public members, while opt-in will only serialize the marked members (regardless of protection level).