# Auto implemented properties and serialization

Tags: c#, .net, serialization

I'm going through a lot of code and marking classes which I now want to persist with the Serialization attribute. I haven't written the binary serialization/deserization engine as yet so guess I will answer my own question once that's complete! - but thought I'd try get an earlier response here if that's OK. I've come across some code which contains a property such as:

```
    public string Id
    {
        get;
        set;
    }
```

Does the "Id" get serialized? I understand that underneath the compiler auto creates a class member, but does this get serialized correctly (since all the data members of the class instance are written to storage)? It feels like it won't since you can't place the Serialized/NonSerialized attribute on properties.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "It depends" on which serialization you use. Runtime serialization, XML serialization, data contract serialization are all different in this regard.

Comment: How do you plan to serialize your class?

Comment: @John: I'm going to be using binary serialization

Comment: Why? Data contract serializer can write XML as binary, and I believe it may be faster.

Comment: possible duplicate of [NonSerialized on property](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7693391/nonserialized-on-property)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can use the `[field:NonSerialized]` attribute to mark the backing field of *events* as being non-serializable, however it seems this is not possible with auto-properties. With auto-properties the backing fields will be serialized and the only way to prevent that behaviour is to transform them into regular properties and annotate the explicit backing fields with `[NonSerialized]` as normal.

Answer (score 3):

As @John has pointed out in his comments, the `BinaryFormatter` (`System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary`) will serialize your auto-generated backing field. You can use custom serialization by implementing the `ISerializable` interface and then decide for your class which values are serialized or not.