# Linq-to-SQL overriding my OnSerializing attribute

Tags: c#, .net, linq-to-sql, datacontractserializer, iserializable

### My Code

```
partial class User
{
    [OnSerializing]
    public void ClearPassword()
    {
        Password = null;
    }
}
```

### Linq-to-SQL

```
[global::System.Data.Linq.Mapping.TableAttribute(Name="dbo.[User]")]
[global::System.Runtime.Serialization.DataContractAttribute()]
public partial class User : INotifyPropertyChanging, INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    [global::System.Runtime.Serialization.OnSerializingAttribute()]
    [global::System.ComponentModel.EditorBrowsableAttribute(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
    public void OnSerializing(StreamingContext context)
    {
        this.serializing = true;
    }
}
```

### Result

> Invalid attribute. Both 'Void ClearPassword()' and 'Void
>   OnSerializing(System.Runtime.Serialization.StreamingContext)' in type
>   'AuthenticationManager.User' have
>   'System.Runtime.Serialization.OnSerializingAttribute'.

Now, did the engineers at Microsoft create a way for two separate blocks of code to fire some events on serialization independent of one another? Especially considering the fact that they hijack this event to set `this.serializing = true`?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

If your `Password` property is using a backing field, [you can set it to `NonSerialized`](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7693410/736079)

```
  [XmlIgnore]
  [ScriptIgnore]
  public string Password { get { return _password;}  set { _password = value; } }

  [NonSerialized]
  private string _password;
```

Comment: I tried getting in and manually adding this to Linq-to-SQL but it deleted it on compile. I want to continue using Linq-to-SQL.

Comment: This works best when using something like Entity Framework Code First... 

It's probably a better idea to have separate objects for database interaction and for storing the structure to disk.