# Make a property deserializable but not serializable

Tags: asp.net, .net, json, serialization, asp.net-web-api

I have a class with property that i want use in json deserialization but i want omit in json serialization.

Example:
I have a class user:

```
public class UserDTO
    {
        public string UserName { get; set; }
        public string Password { get; set; }

    }
```

and I use it in ASP.NET Web API.

I use this class for login and for get all users.
Obviously, in get I want see only username, but in login I need username and password.

I have try to use attribute ***[IgnoreDataMember]***:

```
public class UserDTO
{
   public string UserName { get; set; }
   [IgnoreDataMember]
   public string Password { get; set; }

}
```

or decorate my class with DataContract

```
[DataContract]
public class UserDTO
    {
       [DataMember]
       public string UserName { get; set; }

       public string Password { get; set; }

    }
```

but in this mode I can't login, indeed if I don't use attribute **[DataContract]** or **[IgnoreDataMember]** I can use login, but in get I see password.

I try also [NotSerialized] using backing field, like suggest [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7693410/1970301), but I obtain the same result.

Comment: Which serializer? It matters.

Comment: How can you deserialize a property you never serialize? By definition, you cannot operate on a property that doesn't exist! Also, if this behavior is for security than why are you using string? The main thing I don't understand is what actually is the problem? If you don't serialize the password on transmit, then by definition the receiver won't get a password. So your code is technically working as intended. So is the issue not preserving the password or preserving it? It sounds to me like you need to create a credentialDTO that holds a user and password to keep the two entities separate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Depending on the serializer, you *might* be able to simply add:

```
public bool ShouldSerializePassword() { return false; }
```

This is a well-known pattern that works on many serializers, but not all.

Another common pattern is:

```
public bool PasswordSpecified { get { return false; } set {} }
```

But that is trickier as you need to *also* tell the serializer to ignore it - for example with `[XmlIgnore, ScriptIgnore, IgnoreDataMember]`, etc.

Either way, you probably want to add:

```
[Browsable(false), EditorBrowsable(EditorBrowsableState.Never)]
```

(to prevent the property or method appearing in too many places)

One final option is simply: when serializing, don't give `.Password` a value ;p